# RESTful: Best URI practice in parameterized request of data?

Tags: parameters, rest, uri

Trying to get the grips of best URI practice in RESTfulness...
Let's say that

- **/service/user.xml** returns an xml with all users data
- **/service/user/1.xml** returns an xml with data for user id 1

What if I want to get just the email address of the user(s)?

- /service/user.xml?**par=email** or /service/user/**email**.xml for all users?
- /service/user/1.xml?**par=email** or /service/user/**email**/1.xml for user id 1?

Regards / Jonas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, it makes sense if you think of it as constantly narrowing down your search. You first start with a huge collection of "objects", and refine, becoming more and more specific..

So it goes:

`service -> choosing a particular user -> specify that user id -> specify what you need from them -> specify in what format you want that information`

or `service/user/:id/email.:format`

Alternatively, it wouldn't be wrong to say `service/user/:id.:format?parameter=:param`, if it didn't make sense to create a whole route for something that is potentially trivial.

I think ultimately these specifics don't always have "the best way", but rather several "recommended ways", and one of them will suit you most.

You might find [these](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_State_Transfer) [links](http://www.infoq.com/articles/rest-introduction) to be interesting.

Comment: Thank you, Jeriko! The narrowing approach seems to be the way to go! In my case /service/user/1/email.xml. Great!

Comment: I see the other answer was deleted.. I often wonder about the plural/singular here.. would like to hear some opinions in this regard, as I'm torn. I learnt RESTful design because of Rails, and they guide you toward `/users/` and `/users/1`, even though I intuitively expected `/users/` and `/user/1`. There's actually an option somewhere for `pluralized routes`.

Comment: Hmm, this is interesting stuff... Following your narrowing approach, pluralized versions would be reasonable: /users/ = all users, /users/1/ = narrowing all users to user id 1...

Comment: Agreed.. I might ask a new question about this some time, to get a few more opinions.